# SQLiteDatabase to close or not to close after using

Tags: android, database, sqlite

When I look at examples from tutorials I see that for `getReadableDatabase` the db is not closed at the end but for `getWritableDatabase` it is always closed at the end. Why is that? Even the docs specify that I must call close on `getWritableDatabase`. I have read both docs, so please do not simple quote the docs to me. Thanks.

Comment: see how `close()` is implemented: http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteClosable.java#105, it seems that `close()` has any effect only when #of `acquireReference()` == #of `releaseReference()`

Answer (score 1):

Despite what the documentation implies, there isn't really a relevant difference between `getReadableDatabase()` and `getWritableDatabase()`; both open the database, and that database stays open until it is `close()`d.
So those examples are not correct; they should handle both cases in the same way.

Please note that "when you no longer need the database" does not necessarily mean that you need to close it after each query; if, for example, an activity is likely to access the database multiple times, it is perfectly valid to open it when the activity is started, and to close it when the activity is stopped.

An open database connection reserves some memory for its cache, and the system stops activities if it needs more memory, so you should ensure that there is no open database when there is no active activity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the database open as long as there are cursors in use that contain data from it. I myself rarely close the database, even when using `getWriteableDatabase()`.

Comment: As I ask above, is this because no memory leak will occur if I keep the database open?

Answer (score -1):

As per android documentation [sqlite database](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase())
Writable database "Once opened successfully, the database is cached, so you can call this method every time you need to write to the database. (Make sure to call close()when you no longer need the database.) Errors such as bad permissions or a full disk may cause this method to fail, but future attempts may succeed if the problem is fixed."

As the writable is cached as soon it's opened it means it will take up memory.
And if database is large then huge memory , so not closing it or keeping it open may lead to member leaks.

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Yea, but I see a problem: delete and update are normally overridden with the `close` call at the end. But insert and bulkInsert aren't. My personal understanding is that insert does not `close` because the default implementation of bulkInsert simply calls insert and so calling close after each iteration might be overkill. So there the evidence shows that close is not *necessary* for anything. So is that correct? that `close is NOT necessary*? I.e. No memory leak is caused if I don't close?

Comment: close is necessary. During insert operations it's left to the developer when to close as he knows whether he has more to insert to or not.

Comment: Your ACID remarks are wrong; this is handled by transactions.

Comment: @CL when you do CRUD operations then are those not transactions? And can you tell how do you adhere to ACID properties when using database. According to me it's through CRUD operations.

Comment: The ACID properties are implemented with the help of locks, which are acquired and released at the start and end of transactions. Closing the database is not neccesary to get ACID.

Comment: @CL you mean to say two thread can simultaneously alter a record in android via update query. As according to you it's feasible and data will be consistent.

Comment: The transactions' locks will prevent conflicts by making one thread wait. But two threads can have open database connections without problems.